# Clustering images based on timestamp

Tags: algorithms, cluster, clustering

I want to make folders of images of users in a meaningful way. The images have only the timestamp of creation associated with them. Each folder can have a maximum of k images.

I can use median or mean as a way of deciding which images were taken in a definite time period.

What approach should I use to group these images in folders in such a way that the user is most intuitively able to make sense of the folders?

I am also asking here what would be an intuitive distinction for the user(I cannot use the day or hour of the image to group as I have the k images restriction.)

Comment: Define "best". Community votes, please: is this unclear?

Comment: PS: This has *nothing* to do with group theory.

Comment: Sorry but it seems that you have decision problem: which statistics are to be used for "clustering". There is no best option and using only timestamps gives: you can split by days, by hours (like 16-20 from everyday) or take $k$ elements from start or within hour... And there are more options. Have you considered at least using colors of the images?

Comment: This question is not well-defined.  What counts as "meaningful"?  What counts as "best"?  How do you propose to evaluate any candidate algorithms?  We discourage questions that ask for "best", because what is "best" is subjective and everyone may have their own preference.  Instead, it's better to identify the specific requirements or metrics or criteria you will use to evaluate answers.  Also, we expect you to do thorough research before asking, consider possible approaches, and describe in your question what research you've done and what approaches you've rejected and why.

Comment: Can you use subfolders?

Comment: @reinierpost I thought of that, but I want to be able to show the folders to the user altogether. This did not look very promising.